# Removing inaccessible root CA from AWS managed Microsoft AD

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory, ca, amazon-directory-services

I'm using Microsoft AD provided by AWS. But the machine that the root CA was on was terminated on accident. I tried recovering with snapshots which did not work, and I can't provision a new root CA as we get the following error when we run:

`Install-AdcsCertificationAuthority -CACommonName "RootCA" -Credential $credential -CAType "EnterpriseRootCa" -CryptoProviderName "ECDSA_P384#Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider" -KeyLength 384 -HashAlgorithmName "SHA384" -Force`

> A certification authority with the same name was found in the Active Directory

Given there's no other way to access the domain controllers directly except with an ec2 instance that connects to Active Directory, how can I remove the existing CA to provision a new one?